# What is the command line to get rabbitmq URI?

Tags: rabbitmq

I know this is really basic, but how do i get the url below?

```
uri: "amqp://myrabbitserver.com:1234"
```

I ran the rabbitmq-server already on my local machine

[image]

Comment: You can parse this information (port number) from `rabbitmqctl status` output.

Comment: port number? I couldn't find it. where should I look for it?

Comment: It's 5672 by default